# Inside a class method, get the object name

Tags: python, class, object

Let's see my class (look at ????)

```
class MyInt(object):
    def set_value(_value):
        if type(_value)!=int:
            type_name = type(_value).__name__)
            raise Exception("value of %s cannot be %s" % (????,type_name))
        self.value = _value
```

And ...

```
x = MyInt()
x.set_value(1)
```

that's ok, and ...

```
x.set_value("A")
```

I need this response (best description):

```
value of x cannot be str
```

How can i get "x" (at ????), or pass variable name as argument (implicit)

tnx

Comment: Reason for doing that? Also use `isinstance()` instead of `type()`

Comment: In future i want to use a dict of error's instead the Exception ;)

Comment: I don't think so BrenBarn. (not solve there)

Comment: @JonathanIsaac - you are correct that there is no solution in the linked question.  The answer, however, correctly states that you cannot retrieve the name bound to a value.

Comment: As a side note, this seems to me to be exactly what properties are good for.

Comment: For posterity - if you don't understand why you cannot get the name assigned to a value, read the following http://www.effbot.org/zone/python-objects.htm and http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#other-languages-have-variables